# How to accomplish Persistance Ignorance in DDD?

Tags: java, scala, domain-driven-design, persistence

I am working on the persistence layer of a project that involves `Workspace`'s, each of which may contain zero, one, or more `Document`'s. (I am trying to follow [Domain-Driven-Design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) but my questions may not be directly related to this.)

**Question 1:** Should I separate out persistence? I.e., do you design you entity and value classes in such a way that you can

- Create entities and values in memory, just as you would do without persistence (possibly using a Factory method `Workspaces.newWorkspace(...)`), and
- Call a separate `persist()` method (possibly in a Repository) to take care of persistence?

Or should my factory method `Workspaces.newWorkspace()` create a *persisted* entity (which will be persisted once the transaction closes)?

If the answer to this question is *"Separation, dude!"* then I wonder how to accomplish this in an elegant way. My first approach was (in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org) pseudocode):

```scala
class Workspace(title: String, documents: List[Document], id: Option[Long]) {
  def add(d: Document) =  // ...
  def remove(d: Document) = // ...
}
```

However, if a workspace can have many documents, this is not good (limited by RAM). My next approach, following ["How not to inject services into entities"](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities), was this:

```scala
class Workspace(title: String, docSupplier: DocSupplier, id: Option[Long]) {
  def add(d: Document) = docSupplier.add(d)
  def remove(d: Document) = docSupplier.remove(d)
}
```

With this, the workspace factory can create **new workspaces** like this:

```scala
class Workspaces {
  def newWorkspace(title: String) = new Workspace(title,
    // A supplier that maintains a simple `List[Document]`
    new DocSupplier() {
      def add(d: Document) = list.add(d)
      def remove(d: Document) = list.remove(d)
    }, id)
}
```

Also, my repository can **reconstruct workspaces** it fetches from the database like this:

```scala
class WorkspaceRepository {
  def findById(id: Long) = // ... calls `createDoc()`

  def createDoc(...) = new Workspace(title,
    // A supplier that remembers changes so they can be persisted in `persist()`
    new DocSupplier() {
      def add(d: Document) = changes.rememberAdd(d)
      def remove(d: Document) = changes.rememberRemove(d)
    }, id)
}
```

**Question 2:** Is this the way to do this?! Puh, it's *a lot* of code, with a lot of boilerplate!

Comment: Give it a look at a design pattern called Unit Of Work: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html

Comment: @pabrantes, thanks for the link, that makes indeed a lot of sense. Do you happen to know any implementations of this in Java/Scala that might be reusable here?

Comment: I know one implementation but it's inside an STM (Software Transactional Memory) for Java. Although if you still wanna check the actual code, here's the direct link for the unit of work class (called DBChanges in this case) https://github.com/fenix-framework/fenix-framework/blob/master/fenix-framework-core/src/main/java/pt/ist/fenixframework/pstm/DBChanges.java. As a side note if you wanna go DDD you might wanna give a look at that project, it's pure DDD and hides the persistence 100%.

Comment: as another side note, I've also seen DDD approaches with the repository design you were presenting in your question, but all the boiler plate was generated (since it was always the same). If you want, I can gather everything we've spoken and write an answer.

Comment: the way you are reconstructing the workspace looks like a good candidate for [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) there is a cool Scala / Akka / DDD project using that model that may be interesting to you: [Eventsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced)

Comment: @DavidHolbrook, could you elaborate how you would use Event Sourcing here? I took a quick look at the link you provided but am not sure I understand the link. In any case, thanks a lot for bringing up the connection, it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I separate out persistence?

Yes, just the way that you describe.

> Or should my factory method Workspaces.newWorkspace() create a
>   persisted entity (which will be persisted once the transaction
>   closes)?

No, because persisting a transient entity should be an explicit operation, such as when you add a new Workspace. The factory handles the creation of the object instance and the repository handles persistence. As indicated by **pabrantes** the Unit of Work pattern can be used in conjunction with repositories.

> However, if a workspace can have many documents, this is not good
>   (limited by RAM).

This is a common scenario in DDD - while reaching for persistence ignorance you have to consider technical constraints. The first thing to consider is whether the `Workspace` entity needs to reference the collection of `Document` instances at all. Are there invariants that `Workspace` needs to enforce? Are there transactional boundaries in place? Object references are only [one of the ways of representing relationships](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). Another way is with a repository. So instead of having a `Document` collection on the `Workspace` class, you provide a repository method which allows retrieval of documents associated with a specific workspace. Given that the number of documents may be large, the repository can support paging and filtering as well.

Also take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) for in depth treatment of these issues.

Comment: @euleurfx, thanks a lot for the comments and the interesting links. In my actual implementation, the `DocSupplier` actually provides paging, but it's a lot of code where probably a repository would be simpler (albeit more anaemic!).

Comment: Hm, speaking about transactions, one question I have with the `WorkspaceRepository` above is: can the `DocSupplier` used there make use of the Isolation property of ACID? For example, instead of `changes.rememberAdd(d)` I could _save_ the document to the DB (in the current transaction). The big plus is that queries will return it. The minus: even if you don't call `persist()`, it's actually going to be saved (unless you rollback). I wonder what speaks against this?

Comment: There is no issue with saving a document within a transaction, but I don't see a need for a `DocSupplier` at all. The `Workspace` class can have a factory method for creating document instances, which would then be explicitly saved by a surrounding application service - this would also make it less anemic since workspace provides the behavior for creating documents.

Comment: In my understanding, the `DocSupplier` is here to abstract away that `Workspace`s that are not yet attached to a persistence store manage their documents differently than workspaces that come from the store. In the former case, the `DocSupplier` manipulates an in-memory list (see code) and creates new in-memory instances while in the latter case, the `DocSupplier` contains a reference to the store, accesses it, reconstituting documents. -- So I am not sure I understand what you say: how would your `Workspace` distinguish between docs from the store and new (unattached) docs?

Comment: Why would a `Workspace` need to distinguish between persistent documents (in the store) and transient documents (unattached)?