# How to model an entity with many children in Sorm?

Tags: scala, sorm

I have a `Workspace` and `Document` entities, with the idea that a workspace can contain zero, one, or more documents. My first approach to model this was:

```scala
case class Workspace(name: String, documents: Seq[Document])
```

but this will not scale well since my workspaces may contain *many* documents. Fortunately, my business requirement allow me to treat workspaces and documents separately (in the sense that when I have a workspace, there is no reason or invariant that forces me to consider all documents contained in it).

**Question:** I am wondering: how would I model `Workspace` and `Document` in [Sorm](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#data_types) so that I have a link between the two but do not have to load all documents of a workspace? I imagine to have a [Repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks_of_DDD) that would give me access to the documents of a workspace, with pagination support.)

```scala
case class Workspace(name: String)
case class Document(name: String, /* ... */)

trait WorkspaceRepository {
  def children(ws: Workspace, offset: Long, limit: Long)
}
```

Comment: This is actually my second post in my quest to find an elegant way to achieve Persistence Ignorance. Part I was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836582/how-to-accomplish-persistance-ignorance-in-ddd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy peasy! You define them unrelated:

```
case class Workspace ( name : String )
case class Document ( ... )
```

Then you choose a way you wish them to be linked. I see two.

### Variant #1

```
case class WorkspaceDocuments 
  ( workspace : Workspace, documents : Seq[Document] )
```

And get all documents of a workspace like so:

```
Db.query[WorkspaceDocuments]
  .whereEqual("workspace", theWorkspace)
  .fetchOne()
  .map(_.documents)
  .getOrElse(Seq())
```

In this case it makes sense to specify the `workspace` property as unique in instance declaration:

```
... Instance (
  entities = Set() +
             Entity[WorkspaceDocuments]( unique = Set() + Seq("workspace") )
  ...
)
```

### Variant #2

```
case class WorkspaceToDocument
  ( workspace : Workspace, document : Document )
```

And get documents of a workspace like so:

```
Db.query[WorkspaceToDocument]
  .whereEqual("workspace", theWorkspace)
  .whereEqual("document.name", "...") // ability to filter docs
  .fetch()
  .map(_.document)
```

First variant won't let you filter docs in your query (at least in SORM v0.3.*) but due to ability to set a unique constraint on a workspace it should perform better on workspace-based queries. The second variant is more flexible, allowing you to apply all kinds of filters.

Comment: The result of such queries is Seq[Document]. 

how to extract the Seq[Document with Persisted] objects????

Comment: I found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798020/how-can-i-create-a-different-entity-type-using-the-original-entity-id-in-sorm

In the special case, it may be reasonable to be able to query directly for the with Persisted instance.