# How can I create a different entity type using the original entity id in sorm?

Tags: scala, sorm

I have the following classes:

```
case class Product( title : String, description: String, contract: Contract)
case class Contract(contractType: ContractType, price: Int )
case class ContractType(description: String)
```

and these DTOs:

```
case class ProductDto(id: Long, title: String, description: String, contractType: ContractTypeDto, price: Int)
case class ContractTypeDto(id: Long, description: String)
```

I need to create a method that returns the list of products but with the data filled in DTOs, something like this:

```
def list = Db.query[Product].fetch().toList.map(x => ProductDto(x.id, x.title, 
    x.description, ContractTypeDto(x.contract.contractType.id, 
    x.contract.contractType.description), x.contract.price))
```

The thing is that I can't access to the x.contract.contractType.id but SORM allows me to access to `x.id` (at first level), there is any way to do it??

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you need those DTOs for. Serialization?

Comment: You duplicated `Contract` in your case class definitions and I think the second one is supposed to be `ContractType`.  Can you fix this?  Also, what is the exception you are getting?  Is it a compiler exception or a runtime exception.  Details will help lead to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Casting Approach

You can always access the `id` using casting if you have to:

```
x.contract.contractType.asInstanceOf[ sorm.Persisted ].id
```

### Total Approach

It is cleaner though to utilize pattern matching to produce a *total* function to do it:

```
def asPersisted[ A ]( a : A ) : Option[ A with sorm.Persisted ]
  = a match {
      case a : A with sorm.Persisted => Some( a )
      case _ => None
    }
```

Then we can use it like so:

```
asPersisted( x.contract.contractType ).map( _.id ) // produces Option[ Long ]
```

The benefit of the *total* approach is that you protect yourself from runtime casting exceptions, which will arise if you try to cast a non-persisted value.

### Total Approach With Pimping

You can also "pimp" `asPersisted` as a method onto `Any` using value-classes if you don't find this disturbing:

```
implicit class AnyAsPersisted[ A ]( val a : A ) extends AnyVal {
  def asPersisted : Option[ A with sorm.Persisted ]
    = a match {
        case a : A with sorm.Persisted => Some( a )
        case _ => None
      }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like so:

```
x.contract.contractType.asPersisted.map( _.id ) // produces Option[ Long ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers Nikita. I need the DTOs to serialize the data to send it by a web service that will be used to show a list of product that doesn't show all the data in the products.
The id will be used in a view, for update the entities in the list.
The case class Product is a simplified example, I will have a more complex object, with more data and I don't want to send all the product with my service. It is about performance.
There is any reason for not treat the object in the lambda expression like an object that implements Persisted??

Comment: What you're saying is all absolutely valid, and it is a perfectly normal practice to treat the fetched root entity as `Persisted` (the `x` in our example). What I was saying was that you didn't need to include the ids of subentities (`x.contract.contractType`) in your serialization output, since they were already implied by the id of `x`. In other words all you need to output in your compact serialization are the ids of `Product` (the `x`).

Comment: Thanks again Nikita, it is good to have the participation of framework creator. I don't understand what you mean when you said that the contract id is implied by the product id. Is true that I don't need the contract id in the product list, but let me change the example. First take in mind that the contract type has a separated CRUD, so they don't have the same id number.
If I am updating one product and it's contract type I will need the contract type id to select it in a prepopulated dropdown list to show the actual contract type.

Comment: @FacundoRossi Okay. You have your reasons. Well then you have to do the casting. Although I have a nicer suggestion for you. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Much better than casting directly. Thanks again.